# null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.Keys(headerParam)')

Tags: reactjs, web-services, react-native

Am trying to make web service call but this error keeps throwing in the fetch method.

I actually don't have any header to be passed. It's a plain httpGet call.

```
WebServiceHandler.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',null,null)
         .then((val)=>{
            Alert.alert(val);
           console.log('callapi: ' + JSON.stringify(val))
           this.setState({data:val})
         })
```

The code is supposed to return a list of objects. Any idea where am going wrong ? thanks in advance.

Comment: where is `fetch()` i can see only `WebServiceHandler.get()`

Comment: either dont pass anything or pass { },{ } for those values

Comment: without passing the header and the third parameter didn't solve the problem. But empty params did.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier why is so ? weird behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing empty objects, instead of `null`:

```
WebServiceHandler.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    {},
    {}
).then(val => {
    Alert.alert(val);
    console.log('callapi: ' + JSON.stringify(val));
    this.setState({ data: val });
});
```

Comment: how is this answer different then my comment.

Comment: Yes, this worked! thanks much Oscar. It was the empty param instead of null.

Comment: Why is there a difference between `WebServiceHandler.get` and `Fetch`? I could see **Fetch** returns more data than the other.

Comment: `WebServiceHandler.get` comes from a library, check their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the errors,

```
WebServiceHandler.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',null,{'completed':'true'})
         .then((val)=>{
           console.log('callapi: ' + JSON.stringify(val))
           this.setState({data:val})
         })
         .catch((error) => console.log('callapi:'+ JSON.stringify(error)));
```

Comment: That actually didn't solve the problem but adding empty braces for the header did. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, but this will help you in filtering `{'completed':'true'}` gives results only for `true`